# command 'notepad' on cmd win7 only works in system32?

Tags: java, command-line, cmd, command-prompt, notepad

I just installed my jdk 8 . I wanna create a java in notepad, but the 'notepad' command doesn't work. it says 'notepad' isnt an operable program.
so, i tried to create the notepad by changing my directory first to system32 and i got the command works.
So, what happened here? and how to fix this? Bcs, in my old laptop I used to use the command in my User too, not only in system32.

sorry for bad eng

Answer (score 1):

You probably messed up with the environment variable `path`. Go to Env Variables, path and then add `C:\Windows\System32;` to the beginning of the file

Check out [this how-to](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to see how to set env variables on your OS